# Bootstrap 3 Adding a container-fluid inside a container?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a normal container, and inside this container I want to add a full-width container-fluid, so that the container is Full View Point across my screen.
I tried this, but it's not going full width.

```
<div class="container">

<div class="container-fluid">

</div>

</div>
```

According to me the container-fluid is full width across the container and not the screen. Any way to override it?

Comment: Can also use the grid system.  Use class="col-xs-12" which will stretch a div across the page on any size device.

Comment: @MortHub Anything am posting isn't going full width I really don't know why it's doing that. I need a container across the full screen and it isn't working. It's staying inside the middle Container!

Comment: Do you want to override the width of the container or the container-fluid?
Do not quite follow what you want to achieve exactly.

Comment: @WosleyAlarico I need a container full width, but it's not going full width, I guessed its staying inside the other container.

Comment: is there any specific reason why you want a container-fluid and then override the width? if not then you should remove the container-fluid class.

Comment: @WosleyAlarico I need a full width container in a web-site, and the problem is that while using container-fluid, its not working because the body is made up of a container which is a fixed width.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use `.container-fluid` inside of a `.container` and get what you're trying to achieve.  Look at the code for Bootstrap's `.container` class; it has a fixed width.

You need to use `.container-fluid` OUTSIDE of the fixed-width container.

An example is below:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <p>Some Content</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <p>Item 1</p>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4">
            <p>Item 2</p>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4">
            <p>Item 3</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <p>Some More Content</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

It's perfectly acceptable to have multiple containers throughout the site, wherever you need to make use of a Bootstrap Grid.

Comment: That's right, but is their any way of overriding the following, because I need a full width Container.

Comment: You can use them both; just not embedded in one another.  End your `.container` at the point you need to use `.container-fluid`.

Comment: This is going to be a bit impossible. because the '.container' ends in the end of the body of the web-site and there for if I end it before it's going to make a mess.

Comment: I've updated my answer to provide you an example of using multiple containers.  It sounds like your structure just needs to be updated to better-answer your design.

Comment: Yes that's really good idea. My Problem is on wordpress I need all my pages to be in container, and only some posts I need the container fluid. :/

Comment: That should be as simple as creating an additional page template for those pages that need to be full-width...

Comment: Thanks :) Up-Vote + Answer Helped me a lot

Answer (score 21):

```css
.full-width {
    width: 100vw;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: -50vw;
    left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="container-fluid full-width">
  </div>
</div>
```

This works because you are using `vw` - `vertical-width` which equals enduser's desktop width. This overrides `%` because a `%` is the percentage of a parent, `vh` uses the desktop.

Comment: Perfect answer, especially because it works without position absolute and does NOT assume that it is possible for any case to not use container-fluid within a container.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `row` instead of `container-fluid`.

```
<style>
.container { background: #ccc;}
.fullwidth { background: #000;}
</style>    
<div class="fullwidth">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <p>content</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Row doesn't work either.. it's full width for sure but I don't know what's wrong, nothing going full width across the screen.

Comment: The container is a full width, so even if you add a col-md-12, it's going to stay inside this container fixed width.

Answer (score 0):

Your .container-fluid is the one that has no maximum width and can stretch at a full viewpoint. to get the result you want, the .container-fluid has to come before the .container